# Polymorphic model, Forms and AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, polymorphism

i have two models, Content and Page

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :large_description, :short_description
   belongs_to :contentable , :polymorphic => true
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]
   attr_accessible :active, :menu, :slug, :title, :contents

   validates :title, presence: true

   has_many :contents, as: :contentable
end
```

this is my simple form to create a new page with contents

```
<%= form_for([:admin,@page], :html => {:class => "nice custom"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="formRow">
    <%= f.label :title, "Title"%>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'input-text'%>
  </div>
<%= f.fields_for :contents do |content_form| %>
  <div class="formRow">
   <%= content_form.label :short_description, "Short Description"%>
   <%= content_form.text_area :short_description, :class => 'tinymce expand'%>
  </div>
  <div class="formRow">
    <%= content_form.label :large_description, "Large Description"%>
    <%= content_form.text_area :large_description, :class => 'tinymce expand'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
 <div class="formRow">
    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'button small nice blue'%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

and finally this is my page controller

```
class Admin::PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  def index
    @pages = Page.order("created_at")
  end
  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end
  def create
    @page = Page.new(params[:page])
    if @page.save
     redirect_to page_url
    else
     render :new
     end
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.destroy
    redirect_to page_url
  end
end
```

i have used a namespace Admin.
so the problem is when i send the form, i receive this error and i don't undersand why have a mismatch:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::PagesController#create
>   Content(#70150608194420) expected, got Array(#70150590276780)
>
> activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:204:in
>   `raise_on_type_mismatch' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:308:in`block
>   in replace' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:308:in `each'
>   activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:308:in`
>   replace' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in
>   `writer' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in`block in
>   define_writers' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:in `block in
>   assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in`each' activerecord
>   (3.2.8) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in
>   `assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in`initialize'
>   app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:13:in `new'
>   app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:13:in`create' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
>   `send_action' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in
>   `_run__3558390125630086563__process_action__2004224720818030891__callbacks' activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in
>   process_action' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in`
>   instrument' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in`process_action'
>   activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in`process' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in`dispatch' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in
>   `dispatch' actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in`
>   block in action' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in
>   `call' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in`block in call'
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each' journey (1.0.4)
>   lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`
>   call' rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in`call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in
>   `call' rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in`context'
>   rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in`call'
>   activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
>   activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   *run*_3479256987463636693_*call*_4454778504255292268__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app' railties
>   (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call' rack
>   (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in`call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
>   /Users/ogonbat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service'
>   /Users/ogonbat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in
>   `run' 
>   /Users/ogonbat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`
>   block in start_thread'

this are the request parameters

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"g44p+IPxvdm2ouGAE2u2dV/cCKK8uF6G3XLL4z26zrI=", 
>   "page"=>{"title"=>"zfdzfdsf", 
>   "contents"=>{"short_description"=>"
>
> sdfdsf
>
> ", 
>   "large_description"=>"
>
> dsfdsf
>
> "}},  "commit"=>"Create"}

thank's in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page `has_many :contents`, then it's strange that `params[:page][:contents]` is a hash and not an array...

Either fix one or the other end of the incongruence. If you have a has_many realtionship and you want to create a form for it, prepopulate a number of empty items for it in the main object, and iterating over them, generate the corresponding fields.

You can see ALL responses to [Nested forms in rails - accessing attribute in has_many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249160/nested-forms-in-rails-has-many-confusions) to get an idea on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents` to your `Page` model, I believe this should to the trick ( basically, it should build associated `contents` records from the params [:page][:contents] array )

EDIT

you should also add `contents_attributes` as `attr_accessible` attribute for this to work