# Nested Attribute not Saved in Database (Rails 5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models, `Countries` and `Regions`. I'm trying to set regions to be a nested attribute of countries.  My code so far writes the country to the database, but it does not write the region.  I get no errors.

One other thing I'm unsure of in terms of the relationship, should a user be adding a region with country nested, or the other way round with a user adding a country with the region nested?

**country.rb**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  has_many :roasts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**region.rb**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, inverse_of: :region

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**country_controller.rb**

```
def country_params
  params.require(:country).permit(:name, :description, regions_attributes: [:id, :name, :description])
end
```

**country/_form.html.rb**

```
<%= form_with(model: country, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if country.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(country.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this country from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% country.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :country_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, id: :country_description %>
  </div>
      //nested region form
      <%= form.fields_for :region do |region| %>
    <p>
        Region: <%= region.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

`Region` isn't a permitted parameter. Checking the controller, I have it as a parameter?

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wUtZvA8rMeQ12onWg+B4OcbzGzZOIDOLwi99Aef3SnjAg5yyYA0qI8wNJIl41u/S0+RIlMAvkVwWVyWWPF3Ocg==", "country"=>{"name"=>"Guatemala", "description"=>"", "region"=>{"name"=>"Candelaria"}}, "commit"=>"Create Country"}
Unpermitted parameter: :region
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "countries" ("name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Guatemala"], ["description", ""], ["created_at", "2018-02-02 22:21:24.093876"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-02 22:21:24.093876"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/countries/10
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

**Update 2**

I am now getting regions param allowed, but it seems I'm not actually sending any instruction to create the region.  I've therefore added:

```
  def new
    @country = Country.new
    @country.region.build  //doesn't work
    @country.regions.build //doesn't work
    @country.build_region  //doesn't work
    @country.build_regions //doesn't work
  end
```

but this just produces the error `undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1):

I would change:

```
<%= form.fields_for :region do |region| %>
  <p>
    Region: <%= region.text_field :name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<%= form.fields_for :regions do |region| %>
  <p>
    Region: <%= region.text_field :name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form.fields_for country.regions.build do |region| %>
  <p>
    Region: <%= region.text_field :name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey Pablo.  Have updated the form to `regions` but as per Update to in OP., I realised I hadn't actually been instructing the code to write to that field.  That said, I get a new error `undefined method build`

Comment: Well. @country.regions.build should work.  :) I don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You set up your view & strong parameters to support a `has_one :region association`. `has_many :regions` has some gotchas. You can try [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms), [Nested forms in rails - accessing attribute in has_many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249160/nested-forms-in-rails-accessing-attribute-in-has-many-relation)

Comment: doesn't look like region is a permitted paramater. put the log output in OP

Comment: What you try to do and what I answered is for `has_one :region` association. If you change that it will work. For `has_many :regions` you have to do `country.regions.build` hand handle differently in strong params.

Comment: @SimonCooper update the answer for has_one :region association.

Comment: @SimonCooper Completely changed the answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
<%= form.fields_for :region do |region| %>
```

to

```
<%= form.fields_for :regions do |region| %>
```